# Django: is there a way to load templates in nested folders?

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

in this moment I have an app that has over 100 template files like this:

```
-app/
--templates/
---template1.html
---template2.html
--- ...
---template100.html
```

But I want to separete this files in some folders, like this:

```
-app/
--templates/
---masters/
----master1.html
----master2.html
---components/
----component1.html
----component2.html
---others/
----other1.html
----other2.html
```

Question: is there a way to load templates from folders inside the template folder or all templates must to be located in the template folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, the only thing you have to be sure to check is your settings.py and your view.

**settings.py :**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(
            BASE_DIR,
            'yourapp/templates',
            #'yourapp/templates/componements', avoid to refactor each view
            #'yourapp/templates/masters',
            ... etc ...
        )],
        ...
    },
]
```

just link into the `folder/*.html` like the example below on your **views.py** :

```
...
return render(request, 'componements/componement1.html', {...})
#return render(request, 'componement1.html', {...}), no refactor solution
```

Comment: I have just made some tests and this actually works, the main problem with this solution is that I have to refactor hundreds of render functions. Thanks for your answer, if this question does not get a "dynamic" way to accomplish this without the refactor then I will accept you answer in 24 hours.

Comment: how about you update the settings `'DIRS'` and add `'yourapp/template/componements'` ?

Comment: OMG shame on me for not thinking this approach after read your answer. Thank you. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Do you know if is posible to make it even more dynamic, something like: 'yourapp/templates/*'.

Comment: @Nazkter never tried but might actually work, I'll let you do some testing :)